# how to join 2 tables with 'where'

Tags: mysql, sql

i explain my problem.
I have this tables:

```
      artist                          artist_pic
-------------------       ---------------------------------------
| id | name | age |       | id_artist | picUrl | picDescription |
-------------------       ---------------------------------------
   |                          /\
   ----------------------------
```

For every artist there are many pics.

this is my query (it works)

```
SELECT a.*, ai.* 
     FROM artist a INNER JOIN artist_pic ai on ai.id_artist = a.id  
         where ai.id_artist = '" + idArtist + "' and ai.elemento = 'artist'
```

Now i should "add" another table called artist_video

```
      artist                          artist_video
-------------------       ---------------------------------------
| id | name | age |       | id_artist | video| videoDescription |
-------------------       ---------------------------------------
   |                          /\
   ----------------------------
```

i tried something like this, but i don't get the right records

```
SELECT a.*, ai.*, av.* 
   FROM artist a 
       INNER JOIN artist_pic ai on ai.id_artist = a.id  
       INNER JOIN artist_video av on av.id_artist = a.id
         where ai.id_artist = 2 and ai.elemento = 'artist' and av.id_artist = 
          2 and av.elemento = 'artist'
```

For example, what i should get is:

```
michael jackson   Img/5345.jpg     concert      video/5345.avi     concert
michael jackson   Img/3453.jpg     family       video/2344.avi     family
```

But now i get is this( many times the same record)

```
michael jackson   Img/5345.jpg     concert      video/5345.avi     concert
michael jackson   Img/3453.jpg     family       video/2344.avi     family
michael jackson   Img/5345.jpg     concert      video/5345.avi     concert
michael jackson   Img/3453.jpg     family       video/2344.avi     family
michael jackson   Img/5345.jpg     concert      video/5345.avi     concert
michael jackson   Img/3453.jpg     family       video/2344.avi     family
michael jackson   Img/5345.jpg     concert      video/5345.avi     concert
michael jackson   Img/3453.jpg     family       video/2344.avi     family
michael jackson   Img/5345.jpg     concert      video/5345.avi     concert
michael jackson   Img/3453.jpg     family       video/2344.avi     family
```

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: are you getting more than you want?  Or less?  This doesn't solve your problem but you might only need where ai.id_artist=2 and ai.elemnto = 'artist' since it is the same in the other ANDs.

Comment: Add results and expected out put

Comment: Can you define 'not the right records'?

Comment: You should try to LEFT OUTER JOIN because you don't know how much rows in artist_pic and artist_video do you have.

Comment: If you are recieving the same record few times why don't you just use `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want all the original records, plus the ones with videos.  If so, this might solve your problem:

```
SELECT a.*, ai.*, av.* 
FROM artist a INNER JOIN
     artist_pic ai
     on ai.id_artist = a.id and ai.elemento = 'artist' LEFT JOIN
     artist_video av
     on av.id_artist = a.id and av.elemento = 'artist'
where a.id_artist = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your `WHERE` conditions to this query and see

```
SELECT  a.*, ai.*, av.* 
FROM    artist a 
JOIN    artist_pic ai on ai.id_artist = a.id  
JOIN    artist_video av on av.id_artist = a.id
WHERE   a.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the UNION command to merge your two queries:

```
SELECT a.*, 0 as is_video, ai.primarykey
     FROM artist a INNER JOIN artist_pic ai on ai.id_artist = a.id  
         where ai.id_artist = '" + idArtist + "' and ai.elemento = 'artist'
UNION
SELECT a.*, 1 as is_video, av.primarykey
     FROM artist a INNER JOIN artist_video av on av.id_artist = a.id  
         where av.id_artist = '" + idArtist + "' and av.elemento = 'artist'
```

Note that it only works when you have the same column types for both parts, so you probably cannot use ai.* and av.* but have instead to specify each column individually. I have also added a "is_video" column to distinguish between pictures and videos (if necessary).

If you add the name and type columns for artist_picture and artist_video, this should then give you something like:

```
   michael jackson   Img/5345.jpg     concert
   michael jackson   Img/3453.jpg     family
   michael jackson   video/5345.avi     concert
   michael jackson   video/2344.avi     family
```